# Isn't Fiddler a security hazard when exposed to untrusted users?

Tags: security, proxy, fiddler

Fiddler buffers all the uploaded data from the client before sending it to the server. That means that if you try to upload a 2 GB file Fiddler will try to buffer the whole thing in ram before sending it to the server.
Doesn't that mean is a secury risk to expose this proxy server to untrusted users? All a malicious user has to do is send big requests to consume all the memory from the server and bring it down.

Comment: While this was clearly written by someone with an axe to grind, it misses several important factors (e.g. Fiddler doesn't accept remote connections by default) and servers don't allocate memory the way you think they do.

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT- Seems like you are the one who doesn't know how memory allocation works. Supposedly privoxy can work as a reverse proxy and a traffic logger. Who in their right mind would run a service that can suddenly allocate hundreds of MB or even GB of RAM on a server running other vital services? That person would be insane.

Answer (score 4):

Why would a buffer in the client use up all the memory in the server?  It will just look to the server like the client sent a lot of data very quickly, which it could easily do without a buffer like Fiddler provides.

A malicious user can send really huge requests without Fiddler's help, it doesn't change the capabilities of the client.

Comment: I meant if Fiddler was running in the server, for example as a reverse proxy.

Comment: If you have a component that buffers the entire request, then yes, large requests could be a problem.  If Fiddler isn't sophisticated about this, then don't install it on your server.